# Last slide overlaps first at the end of the slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, slideshow

I've set up a simple slideshow with a parallax effect where the queued slide overlaps the current slide.  All works great until the slideshow cycle completes where the last slide misbehaves and does not reset its position underneath the current slide like the rest do.  I cannot determine why it behaves like this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nolder/zm1Lfa70/1/)

```js
var slides = [];

// Append images to the slides array
$('.slide').each(function() {
  "use strict";
  slides.push($(this));
});

function slideshow() {

  "use strict";

  var $current = slides[0],
    $next = slides[1];

  setInterval(function() {

    // Slide animation
    $current.css('transform', 'translate3d(-30%, 0, 0)');
    $next.css('transform', 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)');

    // Reorder slides
    slides.push($current);
    slides.shift();

    // Reestablish slide variables
    $current = slides[0];
    $next = slides[1];

    // Reset position of slide
    setTimeout(function() {
      slides[3].css('transform', 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)');
      setTimeout(function() {
        slides[3].css('z-index', 1);
      }, 1000);
      $current.css('z-index', 0);
    }, 1000); // END: setTimeout()

  }, 4000); // END: setInterval()

} // END: slideshow()

slideshow();
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main-container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slide-container {
  width: 200vw;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(.48, .14, .31, .97);
  color: white;
  line-height: 60vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
}

#slide-1 {
  background-image: url(https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2015/03/forest-path-germany.jpg.653x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 0;
}

#slide-2 {
  background-image: url(https://media.treehugger.com/assets/images/2016/03/woodland_trail.jpg.662x0_q70_crop-scale.jpg);
}

#slide-3 {
  background-image: url(http://sim02.in.com/4fc598f2c9f2c0cdc5e0decc188d8d10_ft_xl.jpg);
}

#slide-4 {
  background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/fc/88/f9/waterloop-trail.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="slide-container">
    <div class="slide" id="slide-1">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide-2">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide-3">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide-4">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `slides[3].css('z-index', -1)` just be for the end of your `setInterval`. This will send the slide behind Slide1 so it doesn't reposition in the front.

When the slide is repositioned slide 1 has a `z-index` of `0` and slide 4 has a `z-index` of `1` as it is the current slide. So when is repositioned it is the forward most element. By changing the z-index it sends it to the back of the slides and then the rest of the script runs as it should.

```js
var slides  = [];

// Append images to the slides array
$('.slide').each(function() {
 "use strict";
 slides.push($(this));
});

function slideshow() {
 
 "use strict";
 
 var $current = slides[0],
  $next = slides[1];
 
 setInterval(function() {
 
  // Slide animation
  $current.css('transform', 'translate3d(-30%, 0, 0)');
  $next.css('transform', 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)');
  
  // Reorder slides
  slides.push($current);
  slides.shift();
  
  // Reestablish slide variables
  $current = slides[0];
  $next = slides[1];

  // Reset position of slide
  setTimeout(function() {
   slides[3].css('transform', 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)');
   setTimeout(function() {
    slides[3].css('z-index', 1);
   }, 1000);
   $current.css('z-index', 0);
  }, 1000); // END: setTimeout()
  slides[3].css('z-index', -1)   //<======= place here =========
 }, 4000); // END: setInterval()
  
} // END: slideshow()

slideshow();
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#main-container {
 height: 60vh;
 width: 100vw;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#slide-container {
 width: 200vw;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.slide {
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 z-index: 1;
 transition: 1s cubic-bezier(.48,.14,.31,.97);
 color: white;
 line-height: 60vh;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 70px;
}

#slide-1 {
 background-image: url(https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2015/03/forest-path-germany.jpg.653x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 z-index: 0;
}

#slide-2 {
 background-image: url(https://media.treehugger.com/assets/images/2016/03/woodland_trail.jpg.662x0_q70_crop-scale.jpg);
}

#slide-3 {
 background-image: url(http://sim02.in.com/4fc598f2c9f2c0cdc5e0decc188d8d10_ft_xl.jpg);
}

#slide-4 {
 background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/fc/88/f9/waterloop-trail.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-container">
 <div id="slide-container">
  <div class="slide" id="slide-1">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-2">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-3">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-4">Slide 4</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Play with classes instead, look how simple can be your code.
- Use `transitionend`
- You don't need to do crazy stuff nesting `setTimeout` uselessly - and you can have as many slides you want without changing a line of code:

```js
var $slides = $('.slide'),                       // Cache them
    tot     = $slides.length,                    // How many slides?
    c       = 0,                                 // Current Slide Counter
    $next   = $slides.eq(c).addClass("slideIn"); // Prepare first slide

function slideshow() {
  $next.toggleClass("slideOut slideIn").on("transitionend", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("slideOut");
  });
  $next = $slides.eq(++c % tot).addClass("slideIn");
}


setInterval(slideshow, 4000); // Use setInteval Here
```

```css
#main-container {
  height: 60vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slide-container {         
  height: inherit;       /* P.S: why 200% width? :D */
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top:0;
  background: none 50% 50% / cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(.48, .14, .31, .97);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.slideIn { /* CREATE A SLIDEIN CLASS */
  transform: translateX(0);
  z-index: 1; /* 1 is only needed at slideIn */
}

.slideOut { /* CREATE A SLIDEOUT CLASS */
  transform: translateX(-30%);
  z-index: 0; /* 0 is only needed on slideOut */
}

#slide-1 {background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600/0fb);}
#slide-2 {background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600/fb0);}
#slide-3 {background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600/0bf);}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="slide-container">
    <div class="slide" id="slide-1">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide-2">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide-3">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
</div>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```